# how to only return the last element of an array and not get all elements

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Here in the typescript function I receive for downloads all items, but I only want to return the last element of the lists. But I don't know how to customize the function.

Here is my code. blostream is the array [], but i only want to return i=5 for example, if 5 is the last item. How can I fix it?

```
async function main() {
    let i = 1;

    for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);

        const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
        const download = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody);
        console.log(download);
        blobstream.push(download);
    }
    return blobstream;
}
```

Comment: The problem is if I did **return blobstream[blobstream.length-1]** it overwrites the results. The array looks like this blobstream = [1,2,3], first loop it returns 3, then it overwrites, on second loop it returns 2, third loop it returns 1. But I only wants that it returns one time 3 and not 3,2,1.

Comment: But the `return` is outside the loop, right? So why should it return the values multiple times if it comes after the loop?

Comment: Thanks, I was wrong. Solution accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the last item of `blobstream` like this:

```
return blobstream[blobstream.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe it will work for you

```
let result = await containerClient.listBlobsFlat()
let blob = result[result.length - 1]
...
```

hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

With this line of code you can return the last item:

```
let lastItem= blobstream[blobstream.length - 1];
return lastItem;
```

good luck!